# Add language menu to the main menu

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I have menu structure like this:

Home | About | Products

if a user is currently on English page then I need like this:

Home | About | Products | Swedish

and if a user is currently on Swedish language then it will show like:

Home | About | Products | English

1: So how can I add a menu switcher link to the main menu which shows only one language link at a time?
2: What will be the pate for each of the language in the path field while adding a menu link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the help of a friend. I have created a list of two menus lists using menu-block module. One set of English menus and one set of Swedish menus in the following order.

Home | About | Products | Svenska

[image]

and for Swedish

Hem | OM | Produkter | English

After creating the menus , I was unable to provide URL or link to a node (/node/3) OR language (/?language=en) in the path field while creating the link item.

In my case if I change the language such as (http//mysite.com/?q=en) to (http//mysite.com/?q=sv) the above created Swedish menu-block appears. As Swedish menu-block was enabled on Swedish language and English on English menu-block. After that I change one of the hook available in the main theme to my requirement.

I used yourtheme_menu_link() hook in template.php file. Under the set of if statements I added this block.

```
    if ($element['#original_link']['mlid'] == 2662) {
    global $language;
     $lang = $language;
     $lang->prefix = "en";
    $special_link = '<a href="' . url('<front>', array('language' => $lang)) . '">English</a>';
} else if ($element['#original_link']['mlid'] == 2675) {
    global $language;
     $lang = $language;
     $lang->prefix = "sv";
    $special_link = '<a href="' . url('<front>', array('language' => $lang)) . '">Svenska</a>';
}

if (at_get_setting('extra_menu_classes', $theme_name) == 1 && !empty($element['#original_link'])) {
  if (!empty($element['#original_link']['depth'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-depth-' . $element['#original_link']['depth'];
  }
  if (!empty($element['#original_link']['mlid'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-item-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];
  }
}
```

Here 2662 and 2675 is the menu item id. This may help if someone need. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways of doing this, one is to use HTML/CSS to position the language switcher block in the menu, probably a little harder to do with a variable length menu unless you right align it.

Two would be to add the language switcher to the menu, you can use something like http://www.liquidcms.ca/how-to-language-switcher-menu-item to do that.

Comment: I am actually using dropdown menus on my site. I guess the first option is not possible to append the language switcher to the main-menu. 2nd I am new to drupal and coding as well.

Comment: That's probably your theme or modules doing something, by default it's just two text links.

Comment: You're going to want to read up on https://drupal.org/node/361112 it will let you know how to properly do this. Basically you'll want a new custom module with that PHP (in the url above) in there. If you need more help just ask.

Comment: While adding a menu item for language what should I write in the path field ? like mysite/en or mysite/sv

Comment: That is another option if you don't mind not keeping the current path.

Comment: It depends how you set it up in the language settings.

Comment: @Steven - The above link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

[Menu per language](https://drupal.org/project/i18n_menu_overview) module will have the option

> This module enables you to have an clear overview per language what
>   the menu entries are. In Drupal all of these links are on the same
>   page and thus it is not clear in which language it is and the menus
>   will grow very big in time aswell.

Comment: I have made two menu blocks one for each language. Now all I need al-least is to change the url from "mysite/?q=en" to "mysite/?q=sv" when a user click the menu item "Swedish". How can I do that?